# How to scan stdin into variable number of streams

Tags: c, scanf

I would like to scan `stdin` into a variable number of char arrays. Something like this:

```
char words1[num][100];    //num passed as command line argument
i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    While (fscanf(stdin, "%s %s %s ...", words[i], words[i + 1], word[i + 2] ...) != EOF)
    {
         fprintf(outFileStream, "%s", words[i];
    }
}
```

The goal is to split `stdin` into `num` number of file streams for multiple processes to work on sorting the file. I thought maybe `vfscanf` would help but you still need to know how many format specifiers to send to. I guess I could for loop and `strcat(format, " %s")` and use `vfscanf` with a `va_list`? Can someone give an example?

Comment: You have a loop that runs `num` times. How many strings do you want to read inside the loop?

Comment: I'd like stdin to be just one text file less than 100 words. So if I made 4 streams each one would get 25 words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I don't think you need a complicated `fscanf` format but can simply read one string at a time. That is, you can use something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    int num = atoi(argv[1]);
    char words[num][100];
    int i = 0;
    while (fscanf(stdin,"%s",words[i]) > 0) { 
       fprintf(stdout,"Stream %d: %s\n",i,words[i]);
       i = (i + 1 ) % num;
    }
}
```

Given an input file `texta.txt` as follows:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
```

... then the program above will give:

```
$ ./nstream 4 <texta.txt
Stream 0: a
Stream 1: b
Stream 2: c
Stream 3: d
Stream 0: e
Stream 1: f
Stream 2: g
Stream 3: h
Stream 0: i
Stream 1: j
Stream 2: k
Stream 3: l
Stream 0: m
Stream 1: n
```

Comment: Great. Thx for a fresh perspective. I never thought of using the mod operator like that or the string converter. Chosen and upvoted.